# How to remove username from active login table?

Tags: winapi, c#-4.0, vba

I would like to create an application which only allow allow single login session for the same user. i.e. there is no concurrent login for that user.

I have created a table which store the current login list. The username will be removed from the login table when user logout or quit the application.

But when user abort the program abnormally or due to application crash, the username still stay in the login list table. When user try to login again, the system will reject his login as his username is still in the login list.

How do I overcome this problem? How do I remove the username from the login list if due to abnormal quitting of the app?

Your advise is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just have the client inform the server that it's still connected periodically. Any client that has failed to report for a certain amount of time is obviously no longer connected. And the user would have to re-authenticate anyway...

Answer (score 0):

For any user that opens the database (via AutoExec) you might have a hidden form that runs 2 modules on a timer.  The first module will "Check in" every x minutes and add a time-stamp to the login table you have created.  The second will check that for every username on the table, they have an associated time-stamp within x minutes, and if not, remove them from the table.

There are probably more efficient ways to do this, but off the top of my head: add a yes/no "MarkForDeletion" column to your table so you can run an UPDATE query on any time-stamp row that is out of date.  Then run a DELETE query for those rows marked for deletion.

```
Public Sub CheckIn()

'Code to UPDATE now() onto table where you have added the current username

End Sub

Public Sub AuditCheckIn()

'UPDATE SQL here
'DELETE SQL here

End Sub
```

Example of Update SQL:

```
----assuming you are checking in every 2 minutes
UPDATE Logins SET Logins.Deletion = -1
WHERE (((Logins.Timestamp)<=DateAdd("n",2,Now())));
```

Example of Delete SQL:

```
-----Presumably you already have this, just add:
WHERE Logins.Deletion=-1
```